# Find a linear operator $A$ associated with the form $\mathfrak{t}$ where $\mathfrak{t}[f,g]=f(c)\overline{g(c)}$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, sesquilinear-forms

My question is on the title , Let $\mathfrak{t}$ be densely defined form on $\mathcal{H}$. The operator $A$ associated with the form $\mathfrak{t}$ is defined by $Ax=u_x$ for $x\in D(A)$, where

$$ D(A)=\{x\in D(\mathfrak{t}) : \exists u_x\in \mathcal{H} \textrm{ such that } \mathfrak{t}[x,y]=\langle u_x,y \rangle  \textrm{ for all } y\in D(\mathfrak{t}) \}  $$

Now let,$\mathcal{H}=L^2(a,b)$, $\mathfrak{t}[f,g]=f(c)\overline{g(c)}$ and $D(\mathfrak{t})=C([a,b])$. I want to find the linear operator $A$ associated with this.

Maybe another way to write this question is like this:
Find a linear operator $A$ s.t. $\langle Af,g \rangle = f(c)\overline{g(c)}$.

Only thing that comes to my mind is to say $A(f)(x)=\delta(x-c)f(c)$. But as we know $\delta(x)$ doesn't belong to $L^2$ space.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You found your answer and it can’t belong to the space you want

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes that is the problem. Saying $A(f)(x)=\delta(x-c)f(c)$ implies $u_f=\delta(x-c)f(c)$ but at above definition we said $\exists u_f \in L^2(a,b)$ which is not true because $\delta(x-c)f(c)\notin L^2(a,b)$

Comment: I found the answer.   Konrad Schmüdgen (auth.) - Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space has an example like this at pg. 207. If someone writes it from there i could give him\her upvote and accept it as an answer.